# Get Interval between two numbers in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intervals

I`m experiencing some difficulty to accomplish this task...
I Have a Model called Contract, this model has an attribute called sequence that represents the contract sequence number, my question is: how can i get the interval between two typed numbers in a view with this single attribute?

## Model

```
 class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :sequence
    validates_uniqueness_of :sequence
end
```

thanks in advance.

Ps: I was thinking about to create two distinguished inputs to receive the numbers... the questions is: how in the controller or model I create the loop for that!?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `where`:

```
Contract.where(:sequence => start_value..end_value)
```

Similarly in view you can do it like:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
  <%= f.label :sequence, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <% Contract.where(:sequence => #{@start_value}..#{@end_value}).each { |seq|
      <%= f.text_field :sequence, :class => 'form-control', :value => seq %>
    <% } %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, ok, thanks, but in view? how do I do that? I mean, how can I do two inputs for one attribute?

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :sequence, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
  <%= f.text_field :sequence, :class => 'form-control' %>
</div>
</div>

Comment: Something wrong in your code?
(Just to remind) My Model doesn't have start_value and end_value, I'm maybe explaining or understanding it wrong (but anyway, thanks for the help) but I need a way to include two inputs and do the loop from it.

Comment: Its a sudo code. Ive not tried it actually. But it should work fine, you just have to tweak it as per your codebase

Comment: Do you have (and can I add you?) gtalk!?